# Open-source geographical information systems in Smalltalk?

Tags: gis, smalltalk

There is **any** available open-source [GIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_Information_System) framework in Smalltalk? So far I have found these outdated options:

- [GeoSynchrony](http://web.archive.org/web/19990208003342/http://appliedreasoning.com/) : Comercial and unavailable.
- [SpatialWorks](http://www.thefreelibrary.com/Object/FX+Launches+Spatial+Works+Family+of+Embeddable+Geographic+and...-a017262751): Commercial.

and absolutely nothing else for doing GIS like geocoding, mapping, analysis or modelling.